# Count group by with inner join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two related tables on my Oracle Database: EXPENSES and EXPENSETYPE.

I want to show all registers grouped by type of expense, i.e. :

```
| Number  | Description  | Value    | Registers
| 99      | Car Rent     | $200     | 8
| 65      | Food         | $500     | 22
```

...

I tried:

```
SELECT
    ET.NUMBER,
    ET.DESCRYPTION,
    E.VALUE,
    E.DATE
    COUNT(E.ID) AS REGISTERS
  FROM EXPENSES E
    INNER JOIN EXPENSETYPE ET ON E.EXPENSE_ID= ET.ID
  GROUP BY ET.NUMBER
  ORDER BY 
    E.DATE, ET.NUMBER
```

But I'm getting ORA-00979.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all unaggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.  And then you need to do something about the date.  Perhaps you intend:

```
SELECT ET.NUMBER, E.DESCRYPTION, E.VALUE,
       COUNT(E.ID) AS REGISTERS
FROM EXPENSES E INNER JOIN
     EXPENSETYPE ET
     ON E.EXPENSE_ID= ET.ID
GROUP BY ET.NUMBER, E.DESCRYPTION, E.VALUE
ORDER BY MIN(E.DATE), ET.NUMBER;
```